# Run atmx file using command prompt

Tags: automationanywhere

How to run an atmx file(Automation anywhere ) using command prompt?
A bot's extension is atmx. In uipath I am able to run it via command prompt as the extension is xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would for any executable.
If your full path to the atmx file was: `C:\Automation Anywhere\My Tasks\bot.atmx` you can open CMD and simply type:

`"C:\Automation Anywhere\My Tasks\bot.atmx"`

Note the double quotes, these are to deal with the spaces in the path.

Comment: It is not working. Will you be specific about the command I need to run ?

Comment: Have a look at your Default Programs. Windows -> Settings -> System -> Default Programs. Do you see Automation.Player there? If not your probably trying to run an atmx on a machine without the proper prerequisite installation requirements/licenses.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the .atmx file using **command prompt** or **.bat** file.The syntax will be

"C:\Users\username\Documents\Automation Anywhere Files\Automation Anywhere\My Tasks\Main.atmx"

It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the absolute path of task file to AAPlayer.exe as input to run then it will work.

syntax will be like in cmd prompt :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Automation Anywhere\Enterprise\Client\AAPlayer.exe" "/fAbsolute_Path_Of_Task_File_with_extension/e"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the absolute path of the AA player and then the absolute path of the task you want to run as an argument, for example:

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Automation Anywhere\Enterprise\Client\AAPlayer.exe" "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Automation Anywhere Files\Automation Anywhere\My Tasks\ABC_task.atmx"

Save that file as a .bat file. Once that is done change the properties of both the files (.txt and .bat) to Read-only. This is because I have observed that once we run the bat file, it is changing the text inside the text file which would result in failure when running the bat file again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be nice, if you could format it using the markdown syntax.