# How to launch the atmx file programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, automationanywhere

can someone please tell me why my line of code to execute an atmx file isn't working? 
the code doesn't go further after opening the internet explorer :(

```
try
                    {
                        switch (status)
                        {
                            case true:
                                IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.rpachallenge.com/");

                                Console.WriteLine("get ATMX file...........");                     
                                string getATMX = String.Format("C:\\Users\\{0}\\Desktop\\VS Test Environment\\Testing.atmx", Environment.UserName);
                                Process.Start(getATMX);   

                                SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
                                connect.Open();
                                SqlCommand
```

the atmx file get info from sql and fills the fields on rpachallenge.com, capture the ending result then saves in sql.

Comment: Invoke AAPlayer and send that string as parameter

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830795/run-atmx-file-using-command-prompt/56816604#56816604

Answer (score 0):

The .atmx file isn't the executable itself, it's an script file which is executed by the Automation Anywhere runtime (AA.Player.exe) instead. 
You need to ensure that "AA.Player.exe" is installed and is registered application for files with extension ".atmx" on the machine you're trying to execute. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Atmx file runs on AAPlayer.exe, if you have Automation Anywhere installed you can execute ATMX by invoking AAPlayer.exe with atmx file path.

```
        Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Automation Anywhere\\Enterprise\\Client\\AAPlayer.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/fD:\\bots\\mybot.atmx";
        p.Start();
```